# Django what is best way to build query

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I wonder what is the way to build a query.
I'm was trying to use SubQuery or Prefetch, prefetch_related, select_releated but i can't get better results from which I start.

I have situation where I'm getting object instance.

```
object = get_object_or_404(Object, id=pk)
```

then i need to get more data.

```
object.id, 
object.name, 
object.description,
object.update_frequency,
object.resources.values_list('extension'),
object.tags.values_list('name'),                             
object.resources.count(),
object.resources.values_list('file'),
object.resources.values_list('licence'),
object.edited
```

each row is different query. 
How in best way reduce query number?

Comment: Here you access a *single* object, so prefetching will not improve the efficiency. But you should not use `.values_list` unless you absolutely need to, here you can iterate over the `.resources` and thus process the elements, not trhough extra queries .

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would check if the optimization worth it. 
I use [django-debug-toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to have some metrics. For SQL request, you will see how many queries and how much time is spent on each.

Then, I will concentrate on what's important. Good resources to read [are this](https://www.knowlarity.com/blog/dos-donts-improve-performance-django-websites/) and [this](https://hackernoon.com/all-you-need-to-know-about-prefetching-in-django-f9068ebe1e60).

If you provide a complete example, we can go deeper: template, model, etc